# Should I normalize my variables for a descriptive logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, normalization, descriptive-statistics

I'm running a logistic regression in order to descriptively analyze the relationship between my independent and dependent variables. As I understand it, it's not mathematically necessary to normalize variables in order for the logit model to converge. However, if I want to compare my odds ratios at the end and see which independent variables have the greatest effect, it seems like the variables should all be on the same scale, so I should normalize them. I'm thinking that feature scaling so everything is between the ranges [0,1] would be adequate. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give us examples of the right hand side variables that you think you need to normalize before you enter them into your model

Comment: What variable specifications would be helpful, apart from knowing that the variables are measured on different scales?

Comment: For example, are some of your independent variables categorical (e.g., gender coded as male/female)? And could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "see which independent variables have the greatest effect"?

Comment: You don't need to list all of your RHS variables, just give us a couple of variables and their types (continuous, categorical, binary, etc.).  I'd like to understand what about these variables made you think you needed to "scale" them to fit between 0 and 1 and why you think you can't just enter them as-is in the model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpretation of logistic regression with normalized features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355404/interpretation-of-logistic-regression-with-normalized-features)